# I give non-existent arguments to my ParagraphStyle class, start my script, and it doesn't crash. Why?

Tags: python, oop, reportlab

So I was using reportlab to print a PDF. At some point, I used the PargraphStyle class as shown below.

```
style = ParagraphStyle('Main paragraph style', fontName='VeraBd', leading=15, fontSize=12, alignment=TA_JUSTIFY)
```

Here is the thing. At first, I wrote the "fontSize" argument as "fontsize", and I didn't notice it, and my code wasn't crashing. However, of course, the size of the font on my PDF didn't change, which is totally logic. But as the code wasn't crashing, I thought that I wrote nothing wrong, and that I was maybe using the wrong argument, or that I was using it in a wrong way.

I ended up finding my mistake, but this felt strange to me. I'm still a beginner, but when you learn to code, one of the first things you're being told, is that, most of the time, the computer and the programming languages are case-sensitive ; for them "Word" and "word" are NOT the same thing. So in my opinion, if the class recieves a "fontsize" argument (instead of "fontSize"), which she doesn't know what it is, it should make the script crash.

At first, I thought that the reportlab team somehow built things to manage those kind of silly mistakes, but in fact, I found out that you could even give the ParagraphStyle class a completly non-existent argument, and the code still wouldn't crash. A program using reportlab with the following line runs without crashing.

```
style = ParagraphStyle('Main paragraph style', fontName='VeraBd', 
leading=15, fontSize=12, alignment=TA_JUSTIFY, alanTuring="god", iLikeSand=False)
```

I built a little script with only a class and a wrong creation of an instance of this class to verify my thoughts. For example, when running this :

```
class Book:
    def __init__(self, title="N/A", author="N/A", page_nb="N/A", genre="N/A", main_character="N/A", country="N/A"):
        self.title = title
        self.author = author
        self.page_nb = page_nb
        self.genre = genre
        self.main_character = main_character
        self.country = country

animal_farm = Book(title="Animal Farm", publisher="Olaf Scholz")
```

I get a TypeError, which seems normal to me
`TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'publisher'`

So now, how is it possible that the ParagraphStyle doesn't care about non-existent arguments. What is the difference between my example Book class and the ParagraphStyle class ? What makes that one crashes and not the other ?

I asked two people that work as programmers since quite a bit of time, they didn't know. I found nothing on Internet as well.

This is not really a "problem" since I found the mistake, but if you have any idea, know something, or have something to share, I'd be curious to know.

Comment: https://realpython.com/python-kwargs-and-args/ .. TLDR; you are passing named argument and called instance can just ignore those

Comment: The article was very clear. Thanks for the answer :).